# How to disable XCode 8 from displaying files on click?

Tags: ios, xcode8

I am building an iOS app, and have bundled a moderately large json file (around 2MB) in my project. If I happen to click on the file carelessly, XCode freezes. Is there a way that I can avoid opening a file merely by clicking on its icon in the project inspector, and switch to opening files by, say, "control + click"?

Comment: Might be overkill but you could create a bundle and add your JSON to it. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AboutBundles/AboutBundles.html

Comment: Put it in a Folder.